# How to extract currently installed Visual Studio component IDs?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to automate VS2017 install/upgrade VS for new team members by applying the same install configuration as an existing installation.

It seems this can be done using [VS installer command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) parameter `--in <json file>` parameter which could be passed a list of component ids to install as shown in ["Example layout response file content"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/automated-installation-with-response-file?view=vs-2017#example-layout-response-file-content).

While I could manually consider and search for all required component IDs and their dependencies, it would be much simpler to just export the configuration from some existing properly configured VS environment and import it on new install.

**How can I extract the list of currently installed VS workload and component IDs?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run the VS installer as administrator and click **More-Export configuration**, follow the steps, then we will get the **.vsconfig** file that listed the installed workloads and components like the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shown import/export options do not seem to exist in installer 1.17.1298.831 targeting VS2017 Enterprise 15.8.7 (up to date). There's just Modify+Launch+Repair+Uninstall options.

Comment: Yes, the feature is existing on the higher version: 1.18.1076.1019. Please go to Help-Seed Feedback-Report a problem and report this issue to the VS product team, the VS installer itself not update to the latest version and how to workaround it.

Comment: According to Xiu Li [MSFT] on Developer Community:
"Currently, import and export an installation configuration file is the new feature in VS 2017 15.9 Preview".

Comment: @ImrePühvel, thank you for your sharing, like Xiu Li said, please download the preview installer from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/ and run the  preview installer, not need to actually install the preview version, then you will find the VS installer already upgraded to the higher version: 1.18.1076.1019, so you can use the export and import configuration feature.