# Why can't I join my friends visual studio liveshare after we both updated Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-liveshare

For some reason I am getting the following error in visual studio this morning when I try to join my friends liveshare:

> Failed to join a collaboration session. Required setup components may
>   be missing. Please ensure 'Just-In-Time debugger', 'C# and Visual
>   Basic', and 'JavaScript and TypeScript language support' components
>   are installed

It happened after we both updated our Visual Studio. I can not join his liveshare but he can join mine.
How do I ensure the components mentioned are installed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular issue, but in general terms: open up the Visual Studio Installer and ensure the items stated are selected. Some of them may be hiding in the "Individual components" tab or as optional components of workloads.

Comment: Another approach is to share your installation config so that you both have the same components installed (export/import) https://stackoverflow.com/q/52946333/397817

Comment: Thankyou will check it out